# Can't use find_by in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to locate a user by using a find_by method, but I get the error

```
undefined method `find_by_remember_token' for #<Class:0x6650dd8>
```

EDIT: Initially tried `find_by`

This is my sessionshelper where the issue arises.

```
module SessionsHelper
 def sign_in(user)
    cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
    current_user = user
  end

  def signed_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def current_user=(user)
    @current_user = user
  end

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by_remember_token(cookies[:remember_token])
  end

  def current_user?(user)
    user == current_user
  end

  def sign_out
    current_user = nil
    cookies.delete(:remember_token)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
User.find_by(remember_token: cookies[:remember_token])
```

If you wan to use dynamic finders in Rails 4 you should install the activerecord-deprecated_finders gem.

Comment: I tried that originally, but for some reason it also doesn't work--

Comment: which version of rails are you using? what error did you got?

Comment: Also received undefined method, rails 3.2 I believe

Comment: find_by_remember_token should work. are you sure the remember_token column exists?

Comment: Hmm, yea, I did rake db:migrate. I'll try restarting the server.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
User.where(remember_token: cookies[:remember_token]).take
```

it's taken from [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have run `db:migrate` to add the remember_token field to users table